# How can one estimate the parameters of unobserved variables?

Tags: expectation-maximization, latent-variable

Consider three discrete variables $X, Y , Z$ where 
$$X \sim B(p_x)$$
$$P(Y = 1 |X = 1) = p_y,\ P(Y = 0 |X = 1) = 1 - p_y,\ P(Y = 1 |X = 0) = 0$$ I think I can say that $$Y \sim B(p_xp_y)$$
And
$$S = 1-X + Y$$
then$$S \sim B(p_s)$$ where $p_s = (1-p_x) +p_x*p_y$
I have a sample $ s = (s_1,..., s_n)$, of $S_1,...,S_n \sim B(p_s)$.
How can I estimate $p_x$ and $p_y$ using the $s$ sample ?

Is there a way with EM algorithm ?

If i knew for which $i$ $x_i = 1$ occur it would be easy to estimate $p_y$ :
$\hat{p_y} = \frac{\sum \mathbb{1}_{x_i=1} \mathbb{1}_{s_i=1}} {\sum \mathbb{1}_{x_i=1}} $ so I thought I would be able to estimate  $\theta = (p_x, p_y)$ by using EM algorithm. But I do not know how to proceed.

The likelihood of complete data (s,x) is
$$L(s,x;\theta) = \prod_{i = 1}^n [ p_x  1_{x_i=1} p_y^{s_i }( 1 - p_y)^{ 1 - s_i}+ 1_{x_i=0} (1 - p_x) 1_{s_i = 1}]\\
\log(L(s,x; \theta) = \sum_{i = 1}^n [ 1_{x_i=1} log(p_x  p_y^{s_i }( 1 - p_y)^{ 1 - s_i})+ 1_{x_i=0} log((1 - p_x) 1_{s_i = 1})]$$

When $X = 0$ then $S = 1$ $i.e$ $P(X = 0, S = 0) = 0 $,  so the second part of the log likelihood is not defined.

How to do this without going through the log function ?

Comment: You can check [EM for mixtures](https://stephens999.github.io/fiveMinuteStats/intro_to_em.html) as it is essentially your model.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Xi'an.  So the fact that $1_{s_i}$ can be null is not a problem in the expression of my log likelihood ?

Comment: You can move the indicator outside the log. And what matters is the conditional expectation of $X$ given $S$.

Comment: Thanks again but I still can't find the solution. Is the formula of the completed likelihood right ? How can I move the indicator outside the log ?                                                    
When you talk about conditional expectation, is this the E function :

 
$ E_{X|S,\theta^m}(log(L(S,X|\theta)) = 
\sum_{ i = 1}^n  P( X_i = 1 | S = s_i, \theta^m) log(p_x  p_y^{s_i }( 1 - p_y)^{ 1 - s_i}) + P( X_i = 0 | S = s_i, \theta^m) log(1_{s_i = 1})$


So for i such that $s_i = 0$ in the second part of the Expectation I have the undefined expression $0log(0)$ ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, one can write the completed likelihood with no indicator (while omitting $Y$ since it proves irrelevant):
\begin{align}
L(s,x;\theta) 
&= \prod_{i = 1}^n [ p_x  1_{x_i=1} p_y^{s_i }( 1 - p_y)^{ 1 - s_i}+ 1_{x_i=0} (1 - p_x) 1_{s_i = 1}]\\ 
&=\prod_{s_i = 1} [ p_x  1_{x_i=1} p_y+ 1_{x_i=0} (1 - p_x)]\prod_{s_i = 0} p_x  1_{x_i=1} ( 1 - p_y)\\
&=\underbrace{\prod_{s_i = 1\\x_i=1} p_x  p_y}_{\text{$n_{11}$  terms}}\ \times\ \underbrace{\prod_{s_i = 1\\x_i=0} (1 - p_x)}_{\text{$n_{10}$  terms}}\ \times\ \underbrace{\prod_{s_i = 0} p_x ( 1 - p_y)}_{\text{$n-n_{11}-n_{10}$  terms}}\end{align}
which means that (i) there is no indeterminacy in computing the likelihood function and its logarithm and (ii) this likelihood function is parameterised by $(n_{11},n_{10})$, where $n_{11}$ (resp. $n_{10}$) the number of cases when $s_i = 1,\ x_i=1$ (resp. when $s_i = 1,\ x_i=0$).

Hence
$$\ell(s,x;\theta)=\sum_{s_i = 1\\x_i=1} \log\{p_x  p_y\}+\sum_{s_i = 1\\x_i=0} \log(1 - p_x)+\sum_{s_i = 0} \log\{p_x ( 1 - p_y)\}$$
can be rewritten as
$$\ell(s,x;\theta)=n_{11} \log\{p_x  p_y\}+n_{10} \log(1 - p_x)+(n-n_{11}-n_{10}) \log\{p_x ( 1 - p_y)\}$$
Therefore the E function is
\begin{align}E(\theta;\theta_0)&=\mathbb E_{\theta_0}\left[\ell(s,x;\theta)\Big|S_1,\ldots,S_n\right]\\&=\mathbb E_{\theta_0}\left[n_{11} \log\{p_x  p_y\}+n_{10} \log(1 - p_x)\right.\\
&\left.\ +(n-n_{11}-n_{10}) \log\{p_x ( 1 - p_y)\}\big|\textstyle\sum_i S_i\right]\\
&=\mathbb E_{\theta_0}\left[n_{11}\big|S_0\right]\log\{p_x  p_y\}\\ &\ +\mathbb E_{\theta_0}\left[n_{10}\big|S_0\right]\log(1 - p_x)\\
&\ +(n-S_0) \log\{p_x ( 1 - p_y)
\end{align}
if $S_0$ denotes the *sufficient* statistic
$$S_0=\textstyle\sum_{i=1}^n S_i=n_{11}+n_{10}$$
since
$$n_{11}|S_1,\ldots,S_n\sim\text{Bin}(S_0,p_xp_y/p_xp_y+1-p_x)$$
*only* depends on $S_0$ and $n_{10}=S_0-n_{11}$.

Comment: Thank you so much !

If I understand correctly, you never consider the case $x_i = 0$ and $s_i = 0$ because the model would be false and estimating the parameters would make no sense, so in line 3 of the completed likelihood you removed 1_{xi = 0} ?

Comment: In the function E, why did you evaluate it conditionally to $S_0 = n_{10} + n_{11}$ and not to S?
And last question: 
 $n_{10} $, $n_{11}$ are random variables, so $ n-n_{10} -n_{11}$ is too, so why take out this part of the expectation? Is it because knowing that $S_0 = n_{10} + n_{11}$ we know $ n-n_{10} -n_{11}$ ?
Sorry I'm not good in math but thank you very much for taking so much time to answer me.

Comment: The reason is that $S_0$ is sufficient for the computation of the conditional expectation as explained by the law of $n_{11}$ given $S_0$ and that given $S_0$ the value of $n-S_0$ is known, not random.